# Big sized font in body abnormally shifted down

Tags: html, css

In chrome and firefox at least, the paragraph that I use as the header in my website is shifted down as I increase the font size.

A pre-validated html follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>But why?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="font-size: 130px;">BECAUSE!!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/okkdb2h9/)**

Using chrome's `inspect element` feature I see that it is not the font's upper spacing that dramatically increases the space above it, but rather the body that is shifted. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're encountering what are known as "user-agent" styles--those applied by the browser itself. In this case, Chrome applies these margins:

```
p {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

Since the margin units are em values, they're proportionate to the font size. You may override them as you would any style:

```
p {
    margin: 25px 0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/okkdb2h9/3/)**

Comment: So the problem was in the default margins of the paragraph, I guess this is only an issue because I may be using a paragraph incorrectly as a header. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try zeroing the margin of the `p` tag

```
p { margin: 0; font-size: 130px;}
```